# window api programming in c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I am getting a little program in windows API programming. My task is to hide the  window (in my case open Dailog)

So i get the handle for the window it work fine and

```
Windows.ShowWindow((int)ww.hWnd, 0);
```

hides the window. But if i do

```
Windows.ShowWindow((int)ww.hWnd, 0);
Messagebox.show("test");
```

then window doesn't hide!! It just stays there.

What should I do..  I must have to open dialog after hiding windows.  But its not working.

Comment: Where do you call this code (main loop, event handler, ...)? What kind of application is it? What is the return value of the `ShowWindow` function? What does your _actual_ code look like (`Messagebox.show()` doesn't exist in the framework, the class nor the method)? What is the value of `ww.hWnd` in both cases?

Comment: [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);

m hooking dailog
. 
i need to hide it   (hide is working)
but when call my custom dailog (message box)  window hide not work..
it stop there